# How to mock a method with Spectator in Angular Testing?

Tags: angular, angular-test, angular-spectator

I am learning how to test with Spectator the following component:

```
export class CreateRecipeComponent implements OnInit {

  public constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService , private toastr: ToastrService, private router: Router){
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onReceivingRecipe(recipe:Recipe){ 
    this.recipeService.addRecipeAndSnap(recipe).pipe(take(1)).subscribe({        
        next: (res) => { this.onCreatedSuccess(res)},
        error: (err) => { this.onCreatedFailed(err)}
    })
  }

  onCreatedSuccess(res){
    this.router.navigate(["/home"])
    this.toastr.success("A recipe has been created","Creating a recipe")
    return res
  }
  onCreatedFailed(err){
    this.toastr.error("There has been an error with creating recipe ","Creating a recipe")
    return err
  }
}
```

And my current test:

```
describe('CreateRecipeComponent', () => {

  let spectator: Spectator<CreateRecipeComponent>;
  let recipeSnapshot: RecipeSnapshot = new RecipeSnapshot("dummy_parentId", "dummy_recipe", "dummy_description","dummy_userId")
  let recipeForm: RecipeFormComponent | null;

  const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: CreateRecipeComponent,
    shallow: true,
    declarations: [
      MockComponents(
        RecipeFormComponent
      )
    ],
    providers: [mockProvider(RecipeService), mockProvider(ToastrService), mockProvider(Router)]
  })


  beforeEach( () => {
    spectator = createComponent();
    spectator.inject(RecipeService).addRecipeAndSnap.and.returnValue(spectator.component.onCreatedSuccess) //Or onCreatedFailed
    recipeForm = spectator.query(RecipeFormComponent)
  })


  it('should render app form', () => {
      if (!recipeForm){
        throw new Error('recipeForm not found')
      }
      expect(recipeForm).toBeTruthy()
  })

  it('should receive a recipe and add recipe and snap', () => {
    
    let recipe = new Recipe("dummy_recipe","dummy_description","dummy_userId")
    recipeForm.recipeReceived.emit(recipe)

    spectator.detectChanges();

    const recipeService = spectator.inject(RecipeService)
    expect(recipeService.addRecipeAndSnap).toHaveBeenCalledWith(recipe)
    expect(spectator.component.onCreatedSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
});
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to mock the onCreatedSuccess function and how to test that function has been called when the addRecipeAndSnap method has been called?

Do I have to use jasmineSpy? I imagine is similar to mocking RecipeService method but I coould not figure it out.

Comment: Would you mind sharing any tips on getting started with testing using spectator, e.g. sites to use for tutorials or documentation material locations? I've only ever looked at peoples existing stuff but not written anything really in the last 5 years.